# I would like drop down menu selections to bring post different images when different choices are selected

Tags: javascript

Here is my basic pull down selection tabs. How do I get each choice to post a different image (preferably html source images) when selected.

I would like the images to post within the div as well if possible.

```
 <div id= "PERSONAL">
   <p id= "Range"> Preferred Distance </p>
     <select class= "Distance" onchange="report(this.value)">
`     <option value="Pick3">Pick Your Range</option>
      <option value="100 Miles">100 Miles</option>
      <option value="1000 Miles">1000 Miles</option>
      <option value="More than 2000 Miles">More than 2000 Miles</option>
      <option value="Around the World">Around the World</option>
     </select>

    <p id= "Weather"> Preferred Weather </p>
     <select class= "Weather" onchange="report(this.value)">
       <option value="Pick2">Pick Your Weather</option>
       <option value="Cold">Cold</option>
       <option value="Mild">Mild</option>
       <option value="Hot">Hot</option>
       <option value="Anything">Anything</option>
      </select>

    <p id= "Moisture"> Wet or Dry </p>
     <select class= "Moisture" onchange="report(this.value)">
      <option value="Pick1">Pick Your Moisture</option>
      <option value="Desert">Desert Dry</option>
      <option value="Moderate">Wet and Dry</option>
      <option value="Rainy">Jungle Wet</option>
      <option value="Snow">Snow Time!</option>
     </select>

   </div>
```

Comment: Are the images static? One way I could think of is to create the source image dynamically on select.

Comment: use ajax to handle the images!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a placeholder `<img>` tag inside your `<div>` and change `src` accordingly on `change()`.

Just expand on the sample that I provided.

**[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/n7aespfe/)**

Comment: Any reason this would not work in Dreamweaver CS5? I am having issues getting this to work properly. Obviously it looks and works great in your example.

Comment: One thing I could think of is that you are missing the jQuery import.
Or what's the error specifically?

Comment: All figured out. Needed to add   <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js">

Comment: All the best to you mate! Welcome